# How to disable log4net from catching all exceptions?

Tags: c#, log4net

I wanted to implement fake appender that throws an exception when logging particular text.
Apparently with log4net it is extremely difficult. 
I tried to implement my own Appender derived from AppenderSkeleton. 
Also changed ErrorHandler to one that is rethrowing exceptions. But nothing stops log4net from catching all exceptions.

Is there a way to stop log4net from doing it? Preferably programmatically.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean that you want to say, only log error level and higher, and not log the lower level exceptions?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing this. Log4net tries to make sure that any error during logging do not affect the program. See https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#reliability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this. Log4net does not throw exceptions by design. By design log4net does not interact with the running program.

> Is log4net a reliable logging system? No. log4net is not reliable. It
>   is a best-effort and fail-stop logging system.  By fail-stop, we mean
>   that log4net will not throw unexpected exceptions at run-time
>   potentially causing your application to crash. If for any reason,
>   log4net throws an uncaught exception (except for ArgumentException and
>   ArgumentNullException which may be thrown), please send an email to
>   the log4net-user@logging.apache.org mailing list. Uncaught exceptions
>   are handled as serious bugs requiring immediate attention.  Moreover,
>   log4net will not revert to System.Console.Out or System.Console.Error
>   when its designated output stream is not opened, is not writable or
>   becomes full. This avoids corrupting an otherwise working program by
>   flooding the user's terminal because logging fails. However, log4net
>   will output a single message to System.Console.Error and
>   System.Diagnostics.Trace indicating that logging can not be performed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. At least I know there is no solution to that.